# Is it possible to programmatically reboot chromeos devices via google admin devices?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

We have a bunch of devices in Google Admin Devices (https://admin.google.com/ac/chrome/devices)

I can reboot them remotely via the user interface in the aforementioned link. Is it possible to do this via API?